# CSS select text next to a label and input

Tags: css

how to select unwrapped text inside a label that is next to an input?

```
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type"checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
   Apples
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type"checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
   Bananas
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type"checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
   Oranges
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type"checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
   Peaches
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type"checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
   Strawberries
</label>
```

i would like to change the background of the unwrapped text when input `type=checkbox` is checked.

i tried `>*`  but it only works for wrapped elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a pseudo element behind the text:

```css
.myLabel{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.myLabel::before{
  z-index:-1;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background: yellow;
  left: 22px;
  right: -2px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:block;
}
.myLabel:has(:checked)::before{
  background: lime;
}
.myLabel:has(:checked){
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
   Apples
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
   Bananas
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
   Oranges
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
   Peaches
</label>
<label class="myLabel">
   <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox">
   Strawberries
</label>
```

Comment: unfortunately im limited to only just using css, can this be done with pure css only?

Comment: thanks! but how do i only apply css style when input checkbox is checked?

Comment: how about if i want the unwrapped text bold?

Comment: thanks!, works on chrome but not on firefox.

Comment: @RedRam https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility no support of `:has` yet in FF, i hope it will be added soon, otherwise i don't know how to handle the checked input case ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here in search of an answer that doesn't follow the strict criteria of only being able to only use CSS, but one that is widely supported I'd like to mention the possibility of using the "for" keyword  on the label.

With this approach you will however have to add that key to the label element as well as place the select checkbox input outside of the label element.

So the HTML will have to be slightly altered but this actually has wide browser support instead of the has() selector which has very limited support.

```
.myLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.myCheckbox:checked + .myLabel {
  font-weight: bold;
}


<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox1">
<label class="myLabel" for="myCheckbox1">
  Apples
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox2">
<label class="myLabel" for="myCheckbox2">
  Bananas
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox3">
<label class="myLabel" for="myCheckbox3">
   Bananas
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox4">
<label class="myLabel" for="myCheckbox4">
  Peaches
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox5">
<label class="myLabel" for="myCheckbox5">
   Strawberries
</label>
```